# Testing Date Object with Jest using Typescript and i18next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization, jestjs, i18next

included a localization library and I have a date object in my component that looks like this:

```
  getDate = () => {
    const { t } = this.props;
    return new Date().toLocaleString(t('locale.name'), {
      weekday: "long",
      month: "long",
      day: "numeric",
    });
  };
```

When I attempt to run the test, I get the error:

```
RangeError: Invalid language tag: language.name at Date.toLocaleString ()

  15 |   getDate = () => {
  16 |     const { t } = this.props;
> 17 |     return new Date().toLocaleString(t('language.name'), {
     |                       ^
  18 |       weekday: "long",
  19 |       month: "long",
  20 |       day: "numeric",
```

So it's not recognizing the i18n locale. Is this related to how I'm mocking i18n?

My current setup:

react-i18next.ts:

```
jest.mock('i18next', () => ({
  use: () => {
    return {
      init: () => { }
    };
  },
  t: k => k
}));
```

My jest.config:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  roots: ["<rootDir>"],
  testRegex: "/__tests__/.*\\.(test|spec)\\.tsx?",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "react-i18next": "<rootDir>/__tests__/__mock__/react-i18next.ts"
  },
};
```

i18n.ts

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import {initReactI18next} from "react-i18next";
import english from "./locales/en/common.json";
import french from "./locales/fr/common.json";

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
    fr: {
      translation: french,
    },
    en: {
      translation: english,
    },
  },
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false,
  },
  fallbackLng: ["en"]
});

export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mock of t makes it to return the key itself, therefore, `toLocaleString` gets **language.name** as a language, and it throws "Invalid language tag".

My approach with localizing date format is using the [`formatting`](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting) method to format dates by locale.

```js
// i18next.config.js

...
{
  interpolation: {
    format: (value, format, lng) => {
      if (value instanceof Date) {
        const cloneDate = new Date(value);

        return cloneDate.toLocaleString(lng, mapFormatToLocale[format]);
      }
      return value;
    };
  }
}
...

const mapFormatToLocale = {
  YYYYmmdd: {
    weekday: 'long',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
  },
};
```

```
// locale.en.json 

{
  "MY_DATE": "My Date {{date, YYYYmmdd}}"
}
```

```js
// usage of the date locatization

t('MY_DATE', {date: new Date()});
```

The cool part of this method is that you define the date format style inside your translation json files, that means that you can change it per language if needed.

This method is invert the deps between locale & dates, and will work with your mock, because your mock will just return the translation key.

Comment: hey thanks! Just out of curiosity, I have Date called multiple times with different parameters, is it still possible to use your code? And can i put the stuff from i18next.config.js inside i18next.ts?

Comment: Each time you pass a date object as an argument it will apply the formatting. 2. Sure it should be with your i18next configuration :)

Comment: thanks! i'm trying it right now and I get the error that format doesn't exist for this line. Is this a tsx thing?
return cloneDate.toLocaleString(lng, mapFormatToLocale[format]);

Comment: thank you! I had to add an if statement to check if format existed as well! One last question, do you know the appropriate way to render the actual time? I ran my test and I was expecting an actual date:

Expected: "Monday, January 1"
 Received: "dateLocale. MY_DATE"

Comment: From the start you **mocked** the the i18next translation function to return keys.
With this mock you won't be able to test the result of translation function.
You can test that the translation function was called with the proper TranslationKey & the proper date object.

Comment: If you want to test the date formatting it self (why, you don't trust js :] ), you can unit test the `format` function that you've passed to i18next